# "Near to me" or "near me"?

Tags: prepositions

What's correct

> "Near **to** me"

or

> "near me"?

Context: "I'm looking for a supermarket near (to) me". "This school is located near (to) me.", "the place is near (to) you" etc.

Comment: near does not require a to for a geographic meaning.

Comment: @Lambie Then basically you're saying that sometimes it does require the preposition "to". Can you tell me please when?

Comment: Only if you mean emotionally near or close. Then, yes. Otherwise it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, and mean exactly the same.

**Near and near to as prepositions**

> The preposition near (to) means ‘not far away in
>   distance’. Near and near to mean the same, but near is more common:
>
> She comes from a small place on the coast near Barcelona.
>
> My mother loves to sit near the fire at night.
>
> She reached out her hand and drew him near to her.

[(Cambridge - English Grammar Today)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/near-and-near-to)

Answer (score 1):

The *to* in *near to* is largely extraneous; Cambridge's *English Grammar Today* [treats them](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/near-and-near-to) as equivalent:

> The preposition *near* (*to*) means ‘not far away in distance’. *Near* and *near to* mean the same, but *near* is more common.

OALD [adds a note](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/near_3) that

> *Near to* is not usually used before the name of a place, person, festival, etc.

Not only is *near me* [considerably more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=near%20me%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cnear%20to%20me%20%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cnear%20me%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cnear%20to%20me%20%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2010) than *near to me* in both British and American books, but a look through instances of the latter shows many Biblical quotes and other archaic language. In the [NOW Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/now/), *near me* is *31 times* more common.

This is a different matter with some other position-related words; something can be *close to me* but not *close me*, and the same for *next to*, *proximate to*, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

For distance of place:
near (to) me

For distance of relationship
near to me

> He is very dear/near to me.